# chat app using mern stack and socket.io getting slow after sending more than 20 messages

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I am building a live chat app using MERN stack and socket.io . after sending about 20 messages the app gets slow and the users can't write and send a message when another message is sent by other users only after receiving the sent messages .
this is my chat component

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import Messages from "../Messages/Messages";
import axios from 'axios';
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io('http://localhost:5000/')
function Chat(props) {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    const [input, setInput] = useState("")
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/")
            .then((res) => {
                setMessages(res.data)
            })
           
        return () => {
            socket.disconnect();
        }
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {

        socket.on('msgSent', (data) => {
            setMessages([...messages, data])
        })
    }, [messages])
    const renderMessages = () => {
        return (
            messages.map( (message) => {
                return (
                    <Messages key={message._id} sender={message.sender.firstName.concat(message.sender.lastName)}
                              messageText={message.messageText}
                               />
                )
            })
        )
    }
    const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const message = {
            messageText: input,
        }
        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/", message)
            .then(res => {
                setMessages([...messages, res.data])
                socket.emit('msgSent', res.data)
            })         
    }
    return (       
                {renderMessages()}
                <form onSubmit={(e) => sendMessage(e)}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="type a message" value={input}
                           onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}/>
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </form>                
    );
}
export default Chat;
```

this is my server side code

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const homeRoot = require("./Routes/homeRoot")
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http)    
//listening
http.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("hello from server")
})

//Routes
app.use("/", homeRoot)

//socket
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('msgSent',(data)=>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('msgSent',data)
    })
});

//Db connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://@cluster0.agiog.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
```

this is homeRoot where i'm fetching for my messages

```
const express = require("express")
const Router = express.Router()
const Messages = require("../Models/messageModel")
const Users = require("../Models/userModel")
const auth = require("../auth")
Router.get("/",auth,async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const messages = await Messages.find().populate("sender","firstName lastName")
        res.status(200).send(messages)
    }catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send("messages not found")
    }
})

Router.post("/",auth,async(req,res)=>{

    const user = await Users.findOne({_id:req.userId})
    const message = new Messages({...req.body,sender:user})
    try {
        const savedMessage = await message.save()
        res.status(201).send(savedMessage)

    }catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send("error occured")
    }
})

module.exports = Router
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question , i'm new to SO , tried to edit my question and i hope it's clearer now the probelm is that users can't write and send messages only after receiving the upcoming messages and this causes slowing down the app

Comment: Thanks, much clearer. However, I'm still not sure what the rationale is for POSTing the data as well as sending it through the socket. I'd skip the POST and have the socket handler put the message into the DB. Skip the GET and have the socket handler receive messages from the broadcasts. Your current arrangement is like texting and writing letters that have the same content to someone--just text it and skip the snail mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
   socket.on('msgSent', (data) => {
   setMessages([...messages, data])
  })

return{
 socket.off("msgSent");
 }
}, [messages])
```

you need to use socket.off() like this in above example.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Yadnesh have a slight pitfall. Lemme explain.

#### FIRST LETS SEE WHY YOUR CODE HAVING PROBLEM ?

You have placed socket.on listener directly inside your component rather then placing it inside any hook. It means each time your component re renders a new socket.on listener gets created.

- Your component is mounted -> You will have one socket.on listener
- You receive 1st message   -> Previous Listener is still there but due to component re rendering a new Listener will be created
- You receive 2nd message  -> Previous two listener combined will now result in total of 4 listeners

And this pattern continues ..

#### You might be tempted to use code given below, BUT ITS WRONG APPROACH.

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('msgSent', (data) => {
   setMessages([...messages, data])
  });

  return () => {
    socket.off("msgSend");
  };
}, [messages]);
```

#### PROBELM WITH USING [messageList] AS SECOND ARGUMENT TO useEffect ??

The thing is you do not want to create a new socket.io listener each time your messageList is updated. You should always create just one listener for one event during the lifetime of a component. Because once socket.on listener is created then it is not destroyed after listening to first occurance of that event, it just again listens for that event.

So such Listeners must be created once. In your case it should be created when component mounts.

Hence use `[]`, empty list as second argument to useEffect. This hook is equivalent to componentDidMount.

#### CORRECT CODE

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('msgSent', (data) => {
   setMessages([...messages, data])
  });

  return () => {
    socket.off("msgSend");
  };
}, []);
```